I want to update column A of input csv file based on condition of column B. How we can achieve this in dataweave?
"Id","Name","Salary","Location","Date"
123,"Ganesh",10000,"Pune","02/22/2020"
234,"Sanket",20000,"Mumbai","02/20/2021"
345,"Mohan",30000,"Kolkata","01/23/2023"
123,"Ganesh",30000,"Chennai","02/28/2023"
234,"Sanket",40000,"Goa","02/20/2024"

Above is my payload. I want to update Salary to 50000 where location = 'Mumbai' and Date > 01/20/2020.
Unable to achieve yet.

What did you try?

Yes, defininitely show us what you were thinking as you worked toward the answer. More valuable than the excellent answer @aled provided might be validation of your thinking. Maybe you were close and just needed one bit of understanding?

You can use the update operator to conditionally change each record. To compare the date first convert to an actual Date type. Comparing dates using string comparisons is a bad idea. Then map each record using the previously defined update.
%dw 2.0
output application/csv
---
payload map ((item) -> item update {
    case salary at .Salary if (item.Location == "Mumbai" and item.Date as Date {format:"MM/dd/yyyy"} > |2020-01-20|) -> 50000
})


Excellent suggestion and a great us of the update operator.
For consistency with the original dataset, perhaps the lambda for that update case could be: '50000 as String'

In the input CSV column Salary is numeric. Note that the values of Name or Location are between double quotes.
